# Run a certain script JS after x seconds that the page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have this script:

```
<script>
var Webflow = Webflow || [];
Webflow.push(function() {
  MemberStack.onReady.then(function(member) {
   if(member.memberPage){
    window.location.replace(member.memberPage);
   }else{
    setTimeout(function() { location.reload(true); }, 3000);
   }
    })
});
</script>
```

I would like this script to run after 5 seconds after the page loads, how could it be solved?

Answer (score 2):

How about `window.onload` along with `setTimeout` ?

Example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Do stuff here
    }, 5000);
}
```

or, you may also use event listeners

```
function delayAndExecute() {
   setTimeout(function () {
     // Do stuff here
   }, 5000);
}

// Everything but IE
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    delayAndExecute();
}, false); 

// IE
window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
    delayAndExecute();
});
```

Comment: @AlexanderPerez I believe so. Give it a try :)

Comment: if you want to execute function after page loaded you can use ---
 window.attachEvent("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    delayAndExecute();
});

Comment: @elavneet Thanks for reply I So understand the concept, I just can't to understand how to start my script using what you wrote..I don't know where to put my code inside

Comment: Try writing your code inside the setTimeout function - below the // Do stuff here

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
    var Webflow = Webflow || [];
        window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Webflow.push(function () {
                MemberStack.onReady.then(function (member) {
                    if (member.memberPage) {
                        window.location.replace(member.memberPage);
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 10);
                    }
                })
            });
        }, 5000);
    }

</script>
```

So i I tried to do this but the script repeats itself every 5 seconds without taking  `setTimeout (function () {location.reload (true);}, 10)`into consideration; I would like the script to start only the first time in 5 seconds later loading the script

Comment: wouldn't it be better to sleep(5000) and then start all that script?

Answer (score 1):

5 seconds after `window.onload` you are pushing a function into the webflow Array.
But you are never calling it. Add `webflow[0]();` to your code;

```
var Webflow = Webflow || [];
        window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Webflow.push(function () {
                MemberStack.onReady.then(function (member) {
                    if (member.memberPage) {
                        window.location.replace(member.memberPage);
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 10);
                    }
                })
            });
            webflow[0]();
        }, 5000);
    }
```